# Stop google form submit on keypress

Tags: jquery, google-search, google-search-api

I am using google custom search, I tried with e.preventdefault case for stopping form submit, but noting is working as it is providing directly from google.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the `<input type="text">` element where you want to intercept the `enter` key. In plain JS you can do it this way

```
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('my-input-element-class')[0];
```

Now with the element in the `elm` variable, you set an event handler on it to intercept the `keypress` event. Every time a key is pressed in that `<input type="text">` box, it will check if that was `enter` (key code `13`).

```
elm.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
  if (event.keyCode == 13){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

If it was the `enter` key, the event handler will do two things:

- **event.preventDefault()** stop the event from doing what it would usually do, that is, stopping it from submitting the form.
- **event.stopPropagation()** stop the event from "bubbling up" to the parent element, because otherwise the parent would submit the form.

Comment: The prob is there is no name, id associated with the form its only classes which are pretty common every where is the form and tables in the form

Comment: You could use `getElementsByClassName()` then to select the input element. See updated answer.

Comment: this is not working as may be cos of I am using jquery in my code?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to `stopPropagation()` as well. I updated the answer and checked that it actually works. jQuery doesn't affect it.